# A suitable PC for Visual Studio 2010 programming

Tags: visual-studio, virtual-machine

I'm planning on buying a new PC for programming under Visual Studio 2010. My main other usages are:

- Programming under Microsoft Visual Studio.
- Running VMWare Virtual Machines.
- Probably multi-monitor (if my budget lets me buy an extra one)

Here are my questions:

1. Do I need to purchase a high performance display adapter considering my usage described above? or a medium-range one will suffice? In general, I'd like to know how much a display adapter could affect my usages?
2. Which CPU could perform better? Core i7, Core 2 Quad, AMD?  I have a limited budget but I really need a good performance and buying a good CPU/MB/RAM is my first priority.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good video card is *not* a must have, unless you want to develop advanced 3D with Visual Studio (which is an option after all). WPF and multi-monitor can work on any video card you would buy nowadays.

What **is** an absolute requirement is 4GB of RAM, just for Visual Studio 2010 alone under Win7 (x64 obviously, since the x86 version cannot use 4GB of RAM). Adding Virtual machines raises that need. This has no up limit since it really depends on how many VMs you're planning to run at the same time and what application will run on them. Add 1GB minimum per VM running Win7, a lot more if they are supposed to run databases, source control or any heavy load application.

Also, for the VMs, it is almost mandatory to have them use separate physical hard drives if they are going to run simultaneously, if you don't you will experience stone age level disk performance for both the host and the VMs (unless it's all on SSD, which I never tried).

Would I be buying a computer for programming now I would definitely buy an SSD to host Win7, VS and the projects, it would really be comfy (my current desktop takes several minutes to boot and load my projects, anything that improves loading is good).

On the CPU side, you might want to spend money on the number of cores rather than the actual speed (frequency) of the processor. All CPUs have decent performance, but your computer may slow down a lot if you're running several VMs on a 2-core CPU.
the i7 chip is a really good one, but I don't think you would gain a lot buy spending big amounts of money on high-end Intel chips. Go for a good price/perf ratio with lots of cores, which for your budget will be a 4-core i5 or a 6-core Phenom II X6 (I personnally would prefer the X6 but I don't want to sound partial).

More generally, if your host or your VMs are meant to run stuff DBs or continuous integration build or source control servers that are accessible to a lot of people, you might want to use another computer as your developping computer, since availability will be important (that means no reboots, avoid hardware and software failures). You might want to buy a good mobo, and an excellent power supply, plus a good tower with sufficiently numerous fans. And you might want to think of what you're going to use for backups.

Edit: this last line almost excludes pre-built computers, since afaik computer makers will almost always include cheap power supply and motherboard even in high-end computers, because those points are not advertised.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing to look for is drive speed.  Visual Studio does a lot of writing and reading to disk so get the fastest you can.  SSD is ideal.

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of the amazing graphics card, the same rules for gaming setups apply for development environments.  The more resources (RAM) the better, move your default Windows page file location to a drive other than the C: drive, use an SDD or if you cannot afford one then try a hybrid 7200rpm / 4GB SSD drive such as the Momentus made Seagate which will not break the bank.

A lot of people agree that with the 64bit era, memory is the new disk. 48GB will cost around $700 at the moment but this will drop rapidly over the coming months due to a better acceptance of 64bit machines than ever now.

Oh and your graphics card, whilst not needing to be a monster, should still be a better made one (by a decent manufacturer) with the most RAM you can afford.  2GB of graphics ram means that you can have a high resolution image, with multiple monitors, without affecting the host machine RAM.

Best thing for a good Visual Studio setup?  Money.

Answer (score 1):

i7 or core 2, whichever. I'd go quad core if possible,and I'd use as much money as I could on ram.

The Quadcore AMD processors are also quite good now.

finally, considering 2010 is WPF based, a fast video card would also help, maybe not as much as more ram, but I'd go with something more than onboard video.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running VS2008/VS2010 on a triple monitor setup with a really awful graphics card -- ATI Radeon HD3450.  Graphics performance hasn't affected me one bit since I'm just doing *simple* WPF applications.  Your needs will vary if you're doing game development or something more demanding.

I would spend your money on RAM, especially if you're using VMs.  And not only do the VMs need memory to run well, they will also need to use the same disk.  So either put them on a different hard disk, or go SSD.  VS20xx thrashes the drive during compiling, and a fast disk will help you out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can really get a great developer machine if you're willing to **build it yourself**.

**Scott Hanselman** says:

> Jedis build their own lightsabers, so
> you should build your own computer at
> least once!

He describes how he built GOM (God's Own Machine) [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UltimateDeveloperPC20Part2UPDATEAndPODCASTOnBuildingAWEI79AndRFCForBuildingAGOMGodsOwnMachine.aspx) for under $3K, and describes it in a podcast [here](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=238).

If building your own is a bit beyond your aspirations, you can get some good ideas there about the most important features for a developer, from a Microsoft guru who really knows.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it, go for a solid state drive.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider getting a better-than-average video card because you'll need some horsepower to run multiple monitors, since you'll want to take advantage of the new tab tear-off ability in vs 2010 to display code files in separate windows.

I would definitely recommend a 10,000 RPM Velociraptor hard-drive or a pair of them striped because VS is a bit of a hog on IO resources.

If it was me, I'd go with a 6-core AMD Phenom processor and 6GB of Triple-channel RAM to maximize performance. If you're an Intel fan, go i7.

Answer (score 0):

A good read on the importance of **hard drive speed** from ScottGu's Blog.

[Tip/Trick: Hard Drive Speed and Visual Studio Performance](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-hard-drive-speed-and-visual-studio-performance)

> When you are doing development with Visual Studio you end up reading/writing a lot of files, and spend a large amount of time doing disk I/O activity.